# Is this normal if twig doesn't update in realtime

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I'm working on a VPS from OVH with php Symfony 4. I use twig for my view and always work. And a couple days ago all my template is blocked on my old version.

I tried to change some other files like robots.txt, it's work fine. But when I change the HTML of my base.html.twig nothing was change. Futhermore, I tried to restart my VPS and twig still not working. I have no error message, it's working correctly on my dev env but not on my prod env. I have no error message and no clues.

I'm little bit confused, if anyone would have an idea.

Thank you in advance for your help !

Comment: Clear the cache folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it's cache. Try with:

```
./bin/console cache:clear
```

or with

```
rm -rf var/cache/**
```

Comment: Thank you very much ! I'm stupid not to have thought about it before.